# Adding Modifier via Script Node

Tags: python, animation-nodes

How to add/remove a modifier to the object(s) via Script node when "Always" is enabled?

UPDATE:

Just make it finally working with KristofMeirlaen's solution:

Code:

```
obj = Object
UseCutter = GenerateCutter
cuttername = 'AN Boolean Cutter'

if UseCutter is True:
    mod = obj.modifiers.get(cuttername)
    if mod:
        obj.modifiers.remove(mod)
    mod = obj.modifiers.new('AN Boolean Cutter', 'BOOLEAN')
    mod.object = Cutter
    mod.solver = 'CARVE'
else:
    mod = obj.modifiers.get(cuttername)
    obj.modifiers.remove(mod)
```

Comment: Hi Leon, Is your problem that your modifier is added each time the script runs, resulting in lots of modifiers?

Comment: @KristofMeirlaen Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this: basically, we first check if the modifier is already existing. If it is, we remove it.  Afterwards, we add a new modifier and set its parameters.

[image]

code:

```
# get the "Simplesubsurf" modifier
simplesubsurfmod = obj.modifiers.get('SimpleSubsurf')

#remove if it exists
if simplesubsurfmod:
    obj.modifiers.remove(simplesubsurfmod)    

#add a new "SimpleSubsurf" modifier
mod = obj.modifiers.new('SimpleSubsurf', 'SUBSURF')
mod.subdivision_type = "SIMPLE"
mod.levels = 3
mod.render_levels=3

# get the "Subsurf" modifier
subsurfmod = obj.modifiers.get('Subsurf')

if subsurfmod:
    obj.modifiers.remove(subsurfmod) 

#add new Subsurf modifier
mod = obj.modifiers.new('Subsurf', 'SUBSURF')
mod.levels = Subdivisions
mod.render_levels=Subdivisions
```

Comment: Cool, I think I get it working in this way. Could you also add the remove solution? And how to make sure the new modifier is always adding as the last modifier? For example, if I add some other modifier after excuting it, the modifier order will change. How to make sure it will always be at the bottom?

Comment: adding a modifier will always do this at the bottom. I will update the answer to have it remove the modifier first before adding it again. This way, it will always be at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks man. I've updated my code. Can you help to check if there can be some improvements?